# MS Visual c++ "The number of source files and corresponding outputs must match"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile my code on c++ in msVisual2019 but I get an error at every try:

`Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   MSB6001 Invalid command line switch for "CL.exe". System.ArgumentException: The number of source files and corresponding outputs must match. at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowArgument(Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args) at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.RemoveDependenciesFromEntryIfMissing(ITaskItem[] source, ITaskItem[] correspondingOutputs) at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()  HelloWorld  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 687`

This first happened after I created (on accident) a header file inside "Source Files" (img attached), compiled it, then realized my mistake and placed it back in "Header Files". Now every time I build it, even after every change I make...
I can't get this error to go away and haven't found a solution to a similar problem yet.
Any help would be greatly apreciated, thanks.

```
[mistake, build after][1]
[correction, build after][2]
[errors displayed][3]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDAzP.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG54S.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhEsH.png
```

Comment: What VS 2019 build do you have (e.g. 16.10 or something like that)? It sounds to me as a VS configuration problem more than anything to do with your code. Have you updated VS from a previous version?

Comment: Did you just created a new project? If so, what type of project? Empty, console... I don't know if that can affect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up @rturrado, the version is 16.10.3. I did just install vs so the settings should be the default, and the project I started with was an "empty" one.

Comment: I would do a simple test. Create another empty project, just with a `main.cpp` and an `int main() {}`, and check if that compiles. If it compiles, it'd be great news. Then, you could maybe start moving code from your current project to this one.

Comment: I should add that, I have made a slight modification. On project>properties>C/C++>Preprocessor>Preprocess to a file, I selected "Yes /P". This seems to cause the above error actually after the build attempt. When off, i simply get the error ** Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0169 expected a declaration HelloWorld C:\Users\Hp\source\repos\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\EndBrace.h 1 
**

Comment: Yes! That seemed to solve it -rutarro, thanks for the aid.

Comment: `Preprocess to a File` doesn't seem like a good idea according to its description: `This option suppresses compilation...` I'm glad you set it to `No`.

Comment: Did you get it working? Happy for that! Congratulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocess to a File doesn't seem like a good idea according to its description: This option suppresses compilation... I'm glad you set it to No. – rturrado Jul 10 at 21:04
Thanks @rturrado :D